# How can I give a function to each div with a class

Tags: javascript, html

Like how you can.

```
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach((div) => {
  div.onclick = () => {
    console.log(this.dataset.id)
  }
});
```

How can i do it if div was a class .email
How can i make it work?

and how can put a class  and a dataset thorough Javascript because I created an element.

Comment: what are you trying to do ? what is the expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refrain from using `onclick`, or any `onEvent` property on element. Instead, use `element.addEventListener(eventType, callbackFn)`

```js
function printDatasetId(e){
    console.log(this.dataset.id);
}


document.querySelectorAll('.email').forEach(email => email.addEventListener('click', printDatasetId))
```

```html
<p class="email" data-id="adam@hey.com">adam@hey.com</p>
<p class="email" data-id="jeff@hey.com">jeff@hey.com</p>
```

Comment: how can i add a dataset and a class name in javascript because the element .email is created in javascript

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.myClass').forEach((element) => {
  element.onclick = () => {
    console.log("hello")
  }
});
```